# Make requests in loop using restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, restkit, restkit-0.20

In a UITableViewController I try to do this:

In interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tickets;
```

In implementation

```
for(NSString *t in [SharedPreferences getTickets]){

    [[TicketListManager sharedManager] ticket:^(Ticket *sc) {

       [self.tickets addObject:sc];
       [self.tableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"ticket %d", self.tickets.count);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    } ticket:ticketId];
}
```

While all objects are loaded successfully (I logged them), the count of tickets is always 0, so my table wont update. Any ideas why the objects are not saved to the array? I am on xcode 5, iOS7 and restkit 0.20.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `self.tickets` is not initialised. Set:

```
self.tickets = [NSMutableArray array];
```

When you create the controller.

Aside: your method `ticket:failure:ticket:` isn't very clear and would be better as `getTicketWithId:success:failure:`.

Another aside: be careful with starting network connections in a loop as you could flood the network. You may want to limit the concurrent connection by editing the queue of the http client.

Comment: "by editing the queue of the http client" how to do that? You actual answer solved my problem.

Comment: `objectManager.httpClient setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this work -

```
for(NSString *t in [SharedPreferences getTickets]){

        [[TicketListManager sharedManager] ticket:^(Ticket *sc) {

            [self.tickets addObject:sc];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableData) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];

            NSLog(@"ticket %d", self.tickets.count);
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error");
        } ticket:ticketId];
    }

-(void)reloadTableData{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can't be sure exactly what is calling here, but RestKit calls the completion blocks on the main thread by default.